# Query a range of primary keys in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to make sure I get this right,
Based on what I've read so far, you can NOT query a range of primary keys in dynamodb,
like if you have a primary key which is number like the phone number of your customers, you can not get items with primary keys larger than 3010000000 or between 3010000000 and 3020000000
to make it clear, I am not talking about the range key, my questions is about the primary key itself,

so if this is true, there are lots of use cases, like items between dates, users registered after some point, and... , that requiers either table scans,

is this correct?

EDIT: OK, one solution that comes to mind, would be to use only one dummy hash_key for primary key and insert the real key (like phone numbers above) as range keys, does this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can not get a range of `hash_key` with DynamoDb. But this does not mean you are stuck with your use case.

Let's take the 'dates' use case and say your are building a logging application. You are likely to get lots of records each day.

If you use the day as the hash_key, you can put the full timestamp as the range_key. This way, you can split your query into chunks and get what you want.

Of course, to get the optimal results, you will need to know well the kind of queries. For example, what is the typical range ? With DynamoDb, as well as other key:value store, you most of the time model your data with query in mind, unlike SQL when you model with only data in mind.

Of course, if your items spans on larger/shorter range, just adapt this system.

Concerning the "all under the same dummy `hash_key`" sounds like a terrible idea. Sorry. I am not a hundred percent sure how it really works but I know DynamoDB does some sharding across so called partitions. I believe `1 hash_key <=> 1 partitions`. Moreover, If read closely the documentation, you'll notice that the provisionned throughput is splited evenly between the partitions so that each partitions is only allocated a fraction of what you pay for.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are suggesting, but this is too much trouble (which is OK considering what I get in return), but this also means I can't query a time range that spans over the boundary of a day to the next, unless I know in advance and create overlapping keys and ranges, man this is horrible, I think my best bet is to download all the items into my application and do whatever I want there and use dynamodb as storage only.

Comment: I also EDITed the question, would you please have a look again, thnks

Comment: updated my answer. To make it short, I think this is a very inneficient idea but can not guarantee it.

Comment: If you want to get a range of record in between dates, convert your date time to a unix timestamp, store it in the range key then do an IN_BETWEEN query on it.

Comment: @whistlergreg, for dates I usually recommends using RFC3339. It's readable and natural sort == lexical sort. We used this in DynamoDB-Mapper (Python).

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the keys of your primary DynamoDB table, you can add a GSI with a constant partition key and your primary table's partition key as its sort key.

This will enable you to query on the index's sort key and use the resulting partition keys to get the data you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't it going against the best practice which is to use high-cardinality values for partition keys?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is a workaround to a DynamoDB limitation; yes, all the entries would be in the same partition, but the GSI partition would only be used for the otherwise-unsupported queries, and the general usage would be on the well-partitioned table itself. Obviously mileage may vary, depending on whatever else the OP has going on in their solution

Comment: Thanks, those are good points. I’m still learning so I might be wrong. But to my knowledge, even if the GSI is not used, it may still be a bottleneck if it has projected attributes and those attributes are updated often.

Comment: You're not "wrong", it's a question of what the project's requirements and limitations are. Everything in engineering is compromise, and this answer is only intended for the circumstances described in the question. It might be that the OP's choice of using DynamoDb was a poor fit, or it might just be that it's a great fit taking other considerations into account but still needs workarounds like this to make it function.