# Storing timeseries data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am trying to store a bunch of network measurements in DynamoDB and I am not sure of the correct partition key and range key. My data will look like this:

```
{
count: 33,
total: 45,
timestamp: 21231133,
data: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3,
    key4: value4,
    key5: value5}
}
```

I need to be able to retrieve data that has a timestamp between timestamp1 and timestamp2. I will be storing the data every second, and retrieving at a slower interval (maybe every 30 seconds).

I need to avoid hot-partitions and still be able to quickly query the data. I would not want to do a table scan.

Thanks,

Comment: I have moved away from using DynamoDB for this application.

Comment: Keep source of data as Primary-Key, Timestamp (in nanoseconds if you're getting lots of data per second) as SortKey, this would allow you to query data based on every device independently. If the use-case was also to get all the data between a time-frame, you could use a GSI on an attribute that defines the type of device that way you could query [for type-x give me data between StartTime to Endtime]. So every packet would have DeviceID (primary-key), Timestamp (SortKey), DataType(GSIPK), and use Timestamp as the GSISK

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query pattern mentioned in the question, I think "timestamp" attribute should be a PARTITION key. You can use BETWEEN operator when you define the attribute as String , Number or Binary.

On this table data, I don't see any attribute that can be used as RANGE key unless you have any other query pattern or use case.

> BETWEEN : Greater than or equal to the first value, and less than or
>   equal to the second value. AttributeValueList must contain two
>   AttributeValue elements of the same type, either String, Number, or
>   Binary (not a set type). A target attribute matches if the target
>   value is greater than, or equal to, the first element and less than,
>   or equal to, the second element. If an item contains an AttributeValue
>   element of a different type than the one provided in the request, the
>   value does not match. For example, {"S":"6"} does not compare to
>   {"N":"6"}. Also, {"N":"6"} does not compare to {"NS":["6", "2", "1"]}

Comment: Partition keys cannot be queried using BETWEEN operator. You can only get an exact match. You need to use a range key if you want to use BETWEEN. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939131/query-a-range-of-primary-keys-in-dynamodb